# CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install in flutter Mac Mini M1

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

I am not able to run flutter app. I am getting below error :

```
Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
  CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
  Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
  For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

Exception: CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
```

I have tried all possible ways like restart IDE, sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 pod install everything but still getting the same issue.

I am using flutter 2.8.1

Comment: did you install the CocoaPods?

Comment: Are your flutter doctor ok?

Comment: Yes i am using cocoapods. Flutter doctor => All ok

Comment: restart your system n try again

Comment: Tried that also many times but not working

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this problem past few days. This is a weird solution but works for me.

run `flutter clean` and close the android studio and move your project to another directory.
Open the project again and run it.

Comment: Not working....

Comment: Even today I face the problem in a project (not all projects) after updated Android Studio solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. Android studio has released patch for android studio bumblebee !

But now facing another issue `Could not build the precompiled application for the device.`